# Vue3 Composition API emit works without store but not with store

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am using Vue3 with the composition API. I have set up a store (not using VUEX) to store global settings. I have a sidebar that I want to expand or collapse. I first put all of the code in one component to emit to the parent to expand or collapse a sidebar, works great. I then tried to refactor to use the store to have the sidebar set across a views but the emit will not work in the second version.

**Without** using the store, all code is local to the component. It works great and emits  the value to the parent.

```js
//regular
import { ref } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "rightmenu",
  emits: ["showRightMenu"],
  props: ["bgcolor"],
  setup(props, context) {
    const showRightMenu = ref(true);

    function toggleRightMenu() {
      if (showRightMenu.value == false) {
        showRightMenu.value = true;
      } else {
        showRightMenu.value = false;
      }
      context.emit("showRightMenu", showRightMenu.value);
    }

    return { showRightMenu, toggleRightMenu };
  },
};
```

The following uses the store to update the item and run methods.

```js
//with store
import { ref, inject } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "rightmenu",
  emits: ["showRightMenu"],
  props: ["bgcolor"],
  setup(context) {
    const store = inject("store");

    const showRightMenu = ref(store.showRightMenu);

    function toggleRightMenu() {
      const aValue = store.methods.toggleRightMenu();
      context.emit("showRightMenu", aValue); //ISSUE
    }

    return { showRightMenu, toggleRightMenu };
  },
};
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: context.emit is not a function
> at Proxy.toggleRightMenu

Here is the store code:

```js
import { ref } from "vue";

const showRightMenu = ref(true);

const methods = {
  changeColor(val) {
    state_color.color = val.color;
    state_color.colorName = val.title;
  },
  toggleRightMenu() {
    if (showRightMenu.value == false) {
      showRightMenu.value = true;
    } else {
      showRightMenu.value = false;
    }
    return showRightMenu.value
  },
};

const getters = {};

export default {
  showRightMenu,
  methods,
  getters,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your setup function is incorrect.

in the first example, you are using the props as first argument, but not in the second.

`setup(props, context) {` works

`setup(context) {` doesn't because the `context` arg is actually populated by `props` and not `context`